# An automorphic function with no poles is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, meromorphic-functions, automorphic-forms

Daniel Bump calls $f$ an automorphic function if it satisfies the formula
$$f\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)=f(z)$$
where $\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$
in his *Automorphic Forms and Representations*. Now I want to verify that **an automorphic function with no poles is constant**. Bump claims it follows from the maximum modulus principle, but how to explain this in more detail? Should I try to show that $|f(x)|$ has a maximum in $U$ and how to demonstrate it?

Comment: Yes, $\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. I've edited it. @Brian Moehring

Comment: Daniel is the author’s first name. When referencing his book, unless you know him personally and wish to make us all aware of it, you should call him Bump.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I'm sorry to make this silly mistake probably because I'm not a native English speaker. Now I've edited it. @Aphelli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the notion of “no pole” needs to be made very specific: the $j$-invariant map has no pole on $\mathbb{H}$ and is automorphic, yet is not constant. Of course, it has a “pole at infinity”.
If we want to split hairs, we could then consider $\exp{j}$, which does not have a pole at infinity, rather an essential singularity.

We actually want not to consider any of these somewhat pathological situations. Here’s how the classical approach goes.

Because $f(z)=f(z+1)$, you can write $f(\tau)=g(e^{2i\pi \tau})$ for some holomorphic function on the *punctured* open unit disk $g$.

In particular, $g$ has a Laurent series $g(q)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}{a_nq^n}$.

We assume now that $g$ is *holomorphic at zero* ($g(0)$ corresponds to $f(i\infty)$ – if such a thing could be given sense – so we usually say that $f$ is holomorphic at infinity or that $f$ has no pole at infinity. In other words, the “no pole” assumption *has to include infinity*).

So $g(q)=\sum_{n \geq 0}{a_nq^n}$ is holomorphic on the full open unit disk.
This implies in particular that $f(z)$ is bounded on the subspace $S$ defined by $Im(z) \geq 1/2$ (ie $|e^{2i\pi z}| \leq e^{-\pi}$).

It’s an elementary exercise that every point of $\mathbb{H}$ has a $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-translate in $S$: in other words, every value taken by $g$ is in $g(\overline{D}(0,e^{-\pi}))$.

So the local maximum of $g$ on that disk is a *global* maximum on the open disk $D(0,1)$. By the strong maximum principle, $g$ is constant, hence so is $f$.